# @Aspect not found (compile-time) in new, simple Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-tool-suite

All of the examples (I have found) of using Spring AOP in Spring Boot refer to creating an an Aspect/Advice like so:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExampleAspect {

    ...

}
```

When I do this, I get an error *"Aspect cannot be resolved to a type"*.
None of the other AOP related annotations appear to be available either. I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.8 and spring-aop is available on the classpath.  What else do I need to do or add to the classpath to enable Spring AOP?

Comment: Are you using a dependency manager like maven or Gradle? if not try using them as spring-aop itself will have many dependencies and so on, and you'd need to find and add all of them to classpath.

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned this is built by maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POM for spring-aop 4.3.13 includes

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

since this dependency is optional, it must be explicitly listed in your project POM.  Adding it to my project POM (removing the optional element) resolved the compilation issues.

Alternatively, the spring-boot-aop-starter POM can be specified as a parent pom and explicitly lists spring-aop and aspectjweaver as dependencies.

Comment: Yes, it is optional because for Spring AOP you do not need the AspectJ weaver. You only need it for full AspectJ, compile-time or load-time. Actually, for compile-time the weaver is also not necessary, only the smaller runtime. But I guess the developers just wanted to keep it simple because the weaver also contains the runtime.

Comment: Sure, it makes complete sense that it is optional. I didn't intend to imply that it shouldn't be or that there was any problem with the spring-aop pom, simply that the cause of my problem was that aspectjweaver wasn't on the classpath and needed to be explicitly listed as a dependency in my project POM.